# Formatting Question Regarding Latex output from R

Tags: tables

I've recently been trying to generate some Latex formatted tables using the 'xtable' package in R.

However, the formatting of some of the columns is different from the original output.

A snapshot of my original output is given:

```
print(postClassProbs(trial.lca4), row.names = FALSE)
``
MR Mob SC Act Pain Anx Freq      Class 1      Class 2     Class 3
  0   0  0   0    0   0 2845 2.642918e-06 8.776227e-01 0.067042881
  0   0  0   0    0   1  911 4.391841e-07 9.293405e-01 0.030696931
  0   0  0   0    1   0  616 8.220266e-07 9.226063e-01 0.062474787
  0   0  0   0    1   1  683 1.072411e-07 9.719491e-01 0.020051938
```

However, when I run the xtable command, I get:

`````
xtable(print(postClassProbs(trial.lca4), row.names = FALSE))

````\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr}
  \hline
 & MR & Mob & SC & Act & Pain & Anx & Freq & Class 1 & Class 2 & Class 3 & Class 4 \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 2845.00 & 0.00 & 0.88 & 0.07 & 0.06 \\ 
  2 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 911.00 & 0.00 & 0.93 & 0.03 & 0.04 \\ 
  3 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 616.00 & 0.00 & 0.92 & 0.06 & 0.01 \\
`````

In other words, I'd like to ensure that zeroes and ones remain as single numbers, yet xtable changes the format.

Would anyone know how to amend this in terms of Latex table commands?

All help appreciated

Comment: The formatting of the zeros is done by R not LaTeX, maybe you can find something in the `xtable` documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xtable/versions/1.8-4/topics/print.xtable

Comment: Try `?xtable` and then see `digits` or possibly `display`. That should get you to the solution - if not, I'll give it a more serious shot.

Comment: I think this may provide an answer in terms of the point you made on digits. I'll keep pressing away at it.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487421/control-number-of-decimal-places-on-xtable-output-in-r/15487895

Answer (score 1):

Self-answered.

I'd like to thank @vaettchen for pointing me in the correct direction of the digits command however, alongside the contributor on the previous link.

```
xtable(postClassProbs(trial.lca4), row.names = FALSE, digits =c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4))
```